# Numpy: Save time series data

Tags: numpy, time-series

The bellow represents an example of time series data for a grid of 6 positions.

```
timestamp = "2019-10-01"
temp = np.array([(22.1, 22.2, 22.3), (22.4, 22.5, 22.6)])
rh = np.array([(50.1, 50.2, 50.3), (50.4, 50.5, 50.6)])
```

It can be saved to a file for later analysis using `np.savez()`. Thinking in CSV-terms, the goal is to have multiple such *rows* in a single file (`"2019-10-01", "2019-10-02"`, etc.). Therefore, the question is, how to store Numpy array time series data?

Comment: See this: http://tpcg.io/PwMp8Aa1

Comment: Thanks, that gets me an array of the dates. The point is, the timestamp (date) array has a shape of `(X)`, while the rest of the  data variables have a shape `(X, 2, 3)`, where X is the number of measurements.

Comment: Use  `x = timestamp  ` as `x.month, x.year  and x.day`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Just convert the time to be `date =np.array([(x.month, x.year , x.day)])`

Comment: See the code here : tpcg.io/PwMp8Aa1

Answer (score 0):

it is better to store the date as year, month, and day to match your dataset. When you need to return it back to date use `join`.

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy import savetxt
import sys
import pandas as pd
timestamp = "2019-10-01"
year ,month,day = timestamp.split('-')

date =np.array([( year ,month, day)])
temp = np.array([(22.1, 22.2, 22.3), (22.4, 22.5, 22.6)])
rh = np.array([(50.1, 50.2, 50.3), (50.4, 50.5, 50.6)])
a=date.astype(str)

for row  in a:
    x='-'.join(row) 
print(x)
```

See the code [here](http://tpcg.io/PwMp8Aa1)